# How To Speed Up My Brute Force Attack

Tags: python, brute-force

So I have a brute force attacker, and I wanted to see how long it would take to crack my password. However, when I went to a couple of sites like [this](https://www.betterbuys.com/estimating-password-cracking-times/) that estimate your length or places that calculate how long it would take like this one [here](https://howsecureismypassword.net/), they all say that a six-seven digit password could be cracked in under a second!

How can I speed up my brute force program to match speeds like these?

```
# Imports
import itertools
import time


# Brute force function
def tryPassword(passwordSet, stringTypeSet):
    start = time.time()
    chars = stringTypeSet
    attempts = 0
    for i in range(1, 9):
        for letter in itertools.product(chars, repeat=i):
            attempts += 1
            letter = ''.join(letter)
            if letter == passwordSet:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (attempts, distance)


password = "123456"
# Allowed characters
stringType = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
tries, timeAmount = tryPassword(password, stringType)
print("CyanCoding's BFPC cracked the password %s in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (password, tries, timeAmount)))
```

Comment: Step one: Profile. Step two: Optimize.

Comment: Maybe make copies of the intermediate string, instead of constructing from scratch each time. concatenation takes time. It might help or might not.

Comment: @phynju Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your alphabet set is 93 characters.
your pw is 6 characters

the search space is `93^6 = 646,990,183,449`

If you can check `10^7` pw a second, you will still need

`646,990,183,449 / 10^7 / (60 * 60) = 18 hours`

to crack it.

corollary: if you can only check one million pw per second, you'll need 180 hours (over a week)

Comment: How could I speed this up even though I still have 93 characters? Currently, I'm averaging about 2 million passwords per second.

Comment: Reduce the search space. Use more computers. Use a faster language.

Comment: How could I do that? You should put this in your answer since the question is about how to speed up the attack, not how long it would take.

Comment: LOL - what is your target speed @MickeyMouseFL?

Comment: My target speed would be to match something like on the example links that I gave. In those demonstrations, it shows that it could crack them in under a minute.

Comment: Order 1000 billion checks in a minute... you want to increase your current speed 8,000 times... not in python I am afraid; try maybe C or C++ on a multicore machine, or GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python, which is relatively slow.

You could however change your python code to run much much faster.
use **Numba**, it's a Library that compiles your code to assembly(we are talking speed-ups to above 1000X to 1million)

this is Numba's 5 minute guide
https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html

I've used Numba before to Generate primes and from my personal experience its worth the effort to change the code. Most of the time it doesn't require major change.
Example:

```
@jit ##this is most of the times the only change, the jit(just-in-time compiler)
def python_function():
 ... ...
 return xx
```

Note: Major speed-up is provided in CPU-intensive programs Like the one above.